# Java - Big O of addDigits method?

Tags: java, recursion

**What is the big O of this code?** I think its O(logn) because each recursion, num gets /= 10. Otherwise, it must be O(n). Any thoughts on this?

P.S: Not a homework question, just revision for interviews. So answers are welcomed.

```
public class Solution {
    public int addDigits(int num) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0){
            sum += num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        if (sum < 10){
            return sum;
        }
        else{
            return addDigits(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here, what is `n` ? because as I understand , `n =1` always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `O(logn)` is a correct answer, because `O(logn)` only cover the first `while` loop when you compute the first `sum`. But when sum is greater than 10, you'll do another round of computation, which is `O(log(sum))` + another round of computation if the new `sum` is greater than 10. So:

- The first computation is logn
- The first sum will be less than 9 * logn (e.g. if the first number is 4 digits, it will be less than `9999`, and hence the first sum will be less than 9 * 4), so the second computation will be at most log(9 * logn) + computation of the 2nd sum
- The second sum will be less than 9 * log(9 * logn), so the third computation will be at most log(9 * log(9 * logn)) + computation of the 3rd sum.
- So on and so forth

So the final value seem to be `O(logn + log(logn) + log(log(logn)) + ...)` - it will stop when the log(log(...(logn)..)) = 0.

Comment: But doesn't that sequence pretty much equal O(logn)?

Comment: Yes, and no. After the analysis, you can simplify it to `O(logn)`. But I guess in an interview, if you just simply answer that the complexity is O(logn) without the above analysis, then it's not a good enough answer, because clearly you haven't included the complexity of the part when `sum` is greater than 10.